# Failed to create component 'Guna2Button' in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a button control by using 'Guna2 UI' framework in .NET core. When I  drag and drop a Guna2UI button in toolbox it shows an error **Failed to create component 'Guna2Button'**. [image]

Really stuck on this error because of I'm new to C#.

Comment: Reread the warning shown in your screenshot (The one in the error list). I don't see that the Guna stuff you use supports the core Framework. So errors like you show seem to be expected to me.

Comment: I can't get your answer.  please can you explain little bit more ?

Comment: @Pradeep your dependency is not working properly (bowing to the warning window + sheet of dependencies, there should not be yellow triangles there)

Comment: how to get rid of those warning yellow triangles.... is any possible solutions out there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [different version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y3EK4T7M6SvDVpBXdAi4ugfjOHZo5Orv/view?usp=sharing) of the framework. Use only this file and remove other versions of the library from your dependencies.

All versions of this framework: [poke](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i9q_4TnizU34I7gjSEfbpOEzMvxJ-k-A/view?usp=sharing)